# Ant migration tool failing to retrieve process builder flows using sf:retrieve command

Tags: metadata-api, ant, migration-tool

I am trying to retrieve Process builder flows from sandbox org using Ant migration tool and it is failing to retrieve flows with this message :

> [sf:retrieve] package.xml - Entity of type 'Flow' named 'Account_Flow'
>   cannot be found

My **Package.xml** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>    
    <members>Account_Flow</members>
    <name>Flow</name>
  </types>
<version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

**NOTE**: I did not write this package.xml by hand but it was generated by [Salesforce package builder](https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/).

**Build.xml**

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">

    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>


    <property name="sf.username" value="${env.SF_USERNAME}"/>
    <property name="sf.password" value="${env.SF_PASSWORD}"/>
    <property name="sf.serverurl" value="${env.SF_URL}"/>
    <property name="sf.maxPoll" value="${env.SF_MAXPOLL}"/>

    <taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="../ant-salesforce.jar" />          
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>  

    <target name="retrieveUnpackaged">
      <mkdir dir="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
      <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
      <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged" unpackaged="unpackaged/package.xml"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

**Folder structure**:

```
Laptop:~/workspace/DEV_Environment$ tree
.
├── ant-salesforce.jar
└── ANTFolder
    ├── build.properties
    ├── build.xml
    ├── retrieveUnpackaged
    └── unpackaged
        └── package.xml
```

Command output:

```
Laptop:~/workspace/DEV_Environment/ANTFolder$ ant retrieveUnpackaged 
Buildfile: /workspace/Dev_Environment/ANTFolder/build.xml

retrieveUnpackaged:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /workspace/Dev_Environment/ANTFolder/retrieveUnpackaged
[sf:retrieve] Request for a retrieve submitted successfully.
[sf:retrieve] Request ID for the current retrieve task: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYrUAG
[sf:retrieve] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: Pending
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: Succeeded
[sf:retrieve] Retrieve warnings (1):
[sf:retrieve] package.xml - Entity of type 'Flow' named 'Account_Flow' cannot be found
[sf:retrieve] Finished request YYYYYYYYYYYYYYrUAG successfully.
```

There is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ZBfAAM) for the same error but it says this error will happen only if we use the `sf:bulkRetrieve` and workaround suggested is to use `sf:retrieve`. I am using `sf:retrieve` and still getting the error.

I tried with Ant jar 42.0 and still same output.

Anyone ran into same error?

Comment: I guess, version is also required while fetching particular process builder - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/211658/25920

Comment: Just confirmed that myself--you need to include the version you want to retrieve.

Comment: I just ran with wildcard character as  `<Flow>*</Flow>`  and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, the old method of retrieving Process Builder flows required a -version_number at the end of the name like so: process_builder_flow-1, where -1 is the version number, .

This is no longer necessary as of [API version 44](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fullname_upgrade_md.htm?edition=&impact=). So the code from the question should have no problem during the retrieve now.