# Compare Flow Versions

Tags: visual-workflow, sourcecontrol

Now that Flows are being pushed more and more, I would like to facilitate the code review of those.

Have you found a way to visualize the difference between flow versions (for non-XML nerds)?

I came across [this open-source tool](https://unofficialsf.com/analyze-flows-compares-two-flow-versions-and-reports-on-the-differences/) with some potential, and I'm sure I'm not the only one on this boat.

**Note**: I recall this old [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/365605/compare-differences-between-two-versions-of-a-flow) & this [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWKoUAN/allow-different-versions-of-process-builder-and-vf-flows-to-be-compared).

Comment: you are not the only one who wants this :-)